# How do I make a tabbar item available only for a specific target?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, target, uitabbaritem

I have a `tabBarController` with three `items` to different `viewControllers`. There are four `targets` in my projects and for one of the `targets` I would like to add a new `tabBar` `item` that goes to `newViewController`. The `item` shouldn't show up when I run the other `targets`.

First I thought it was as easy as setting the `newViewController` to only be available to the specific `target` that I wanted, and that it would not show up in the `tabBar` if I ran the project under a different `target`. But the app crashed.

Is there a way to hide/show the `tabBar` `item` based on `target` without using the `#if target` code. We try to get away from that in the project. It would be nice to just do it in the `storyBoard` if that's possible. If not, then there is a custom `tabBar` class available. Let me know if you need to see some code from it.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this in my project. But, I did everything programmatically. I don't know if that what you actually need. Based on condition `if else` I'm showing or hiding a `tabBarItem`. Is this what you need?

Comment: We are staying away from if/else, but I actually managed to solve it by having two sets of storyboards, one with the extra item, and then assigning them to their respective target.

Comment: So in my case, I had different ids for different targets. I would compare the ids to check which target is currently executed and setup `tabBar` accordingly. I think my approach is much easier if you are able to do implement it this way.

Comment: Ah, ok, so you set the id in the storyboards? But you still use conditionals to check target in the tabBar class?

Comment: Since this comment section was getting really long I have posted a small gist of my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comment section was getting really messy I thought I'd post the gist of how my approach for a different set of `UITabBarItem` for different target went. So firstly I created a static `Environment` variable for letting me know which target was getting executed. Here is the code:

```
enum Target {
    case targetOne, targetTwo

    static var current: Target {
        Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier?.contains("targetOneIdentifier") == true ? .targetOne : .targetTwo
    }
}
```

Then inside `UITabBarController`, I'm setting the `viewControllers` property according to the current target. This is some code in TabBarController:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bool = Target.current == .targetOne
        let targetBasedViewController: UIViewController = bool ? FirstViewController() : SecondViewController()
        targetBasedViewController.tabBarItem.title = bool ? "First" : "Second"
        targetBasedViewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: bool ? "First" : "Second")
    }
}
```

Note: This is just the gist of customisation I did. The whole thing is really lengthy and would be really hard to understand considering the scenario.

Comment: Ok, that's really nice, thank you for elaborating! :D

Comment: Ok, did it your way, starting with four tabs, then removing one based info.plist: `if Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "RemoveTabItem") as? Bool ?? true { viewControllers?.remove(at: 1) }`

Comment: I did not. It wasn't required for my scenario. I'm sure that could work as well if the right logic is applied.